# How to print data with Thymeleaf

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I am new to Spring MVC and trying to list some data on the view by using Thymeleaf

Controller

```
   @RequestMapping("/booksWithMultipleAuthors")
    public String booksWithMultipleAuthors(Model model) {

        model.addAttribute("booksWithMultipleAuthors", this.userService.getAllWithAuthors());

        return "booksWithMultipleAuthors";
    }
```

View:

```
<div th:each="author : *{authors}" th:object="${author}">
    <a th:text="${author.name}">Author name:</a>
</div>
```

I am able to list books but when it comes to list authors i am getting `HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Error during execution of processor 'org.thymeleaf.standard.processor.attr.StandardEachAttrProcessor' (booksWithMultipleAuthors)` error. How do i fix this ?

Comment: Can you post the error stacktrace?

Comment: @Lukehey done updated the question

Answer (score 1):

The attribute name you are adding to the model does not match the object you are trying to access in your view.

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping("/booksWithMultipleAuthors")
    public String booksWithMultipleAuthors(Model model) {

        model.addAttribute("authors", this.userService.getAllWithAuthors());

        return "booksWithMultipleAuthors";
    }
```

View:

```
<div th:each="author : ${authors}">
    <a th:text="${author.name}">Author name:</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Tried this one before, error has gone but items does not appear on the view.

Comment: Are you sure your service provides the correct data? What is the return type of getAllWithAuthors?

Comment: The exact type. Is it a collection of a String or some custom object? Book? Author?

Comment: Collection of Authors

Comment: Are you sure that your aren't receiving an empty collection?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97773/discussion-between-tartar-and-lukehey).